# If I play multiplayer and broadcast it on twitch, can the other players hear me?

Tags: xbox-one, twitch

If I do a broadcast of me doing a multiplayer game, I don't want to drive the other players crazy with my commentary.  Can I do a multiplayer game on twitch, talk, and the other players not hear me (unless they are watching on twitch)?

Edit:  I am using Xbox One.
Edit:  I found it.  Use Party but don't invite anyone and require invites.

Answer (score 0):

In 99% of games, you need third party software to stream that game on twitch, and when third party software is being used, then other players will not be able to hear your commentating.

If you are using a built-in feature to stream on twitch, they shouldn't be able to hear you and they probably won't.

Comment: I edited.  I am on Xbox One.

Comment: can other people hear you if you are NOT streaming?

Comment: Yeah.  It's regular chat then, or so I thought.

Comment: check your settings to turn off that feature, then you should be fine, but make sure it's not your mic you're turning off

Answer (score 0):

Use Party and don't invite anyone and require invites: